# Form in master page not submitted

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on asp.net application. In master page of my application, I have a sidebar div. I have inserted a form in it for subscription which looks like this:

```
<form method="post" action="https://app.icontact.com/icp/signup.php" name="icpsignup" id="icpsignup3297" accept-charset="UTF-8" onsubmit="return verifyRequired3297();" >
   ...
   <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Get Deals">
<form>
```

And javascript function which is called on button click looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var icpForm3297 = document.getElementById('icpsignup3297');

    if (document.location.protocol === "https:")
        icpForm3297.action = "https://app.icontact.com/icp/signup.php";

    function verifyRequired3297() {  
        alert('testing');     
        if (icpForm3297["fields_email"].value == "") {
            icpForm3297["fields_email"].focus();
            alert("The Email field is required.");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

when I hit submit button, page reloads but form is not redirected to other page (redirection url) Is it because the code is in master page? Even test alert is not shown.

If I use this code in a new asp.net page without master page, it works perfectly

Comment: A masterpage is not the same as .aspx page. Why not convert your form to a user control and include a reference to it in the masterpage so that all subsequent pages get it?

Comment: Duane: If i create a user control and paste it on master page at the same location, it will be accessible to all the pages as it is now but making it user control will redirect to the desired location ?

Comment: I mean, create a content placeholder for it within the `.masterpage`, then in your .aspx pages populate the user control placeholder with the actual user control e.g. `<uc:MyUserControl id="Form" runat=server />` etc....

Comment: do I need to put this user control in that placeholder in all pages ?

Comment: Only in pages where you want it, but if you initially had it in a masterpage it's safe to assume you wanted it in all pages so i'd say yes.

Comment: Can you confirm that the `<form>` is not contained **within** (i.e. nested in) the main `<form runat="server">`?

Comment: @freefaller: sorry, I double checked. master page has another base master page which has form tag like this:  <form id="form1" runat="server"> so there are two form tags. How to deal this situation so that second form is submitted ?

Comment: @DotnetSparrow, sorry, I have to leave for the evening... I hope my answer gives you an idea of how you *could* solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

Base on question comments by OP...

It is invalid HTML to have nested `<form>` tags (whether they are marked as `runat="server"` or not). For example, this is not allowed and will fail...

```
<form>
  ...
  <form>
    ...
  </form>
  ...
</form>
```

The only thing I can think to do is something like the following...

- Create a new `<form>` based on the one in your question, outside of the main `<form runat="server">`
- Populate the new `<form>` with all the `<input type="hidden">` fields that you need to pass
- Remove the `<form>` tags from the original location, leaving the controls / layout that the user is going to use
- Set a handler such as `onclick="submitMyForm();return false;"` onto the original `<input type="submit">` (or replace it with a normal button - either HTML or ASP.NET based - and set the handler to that)
- Create JavaScript function to call

The javascript function could look something like this...

```
function submitMyForm(){
  document.getElementById("myNewFormCtrl1").value = 
    document.getElementById("<%=myOldFormCtrl1.ClientId%>").value;
  ...
  document.getElementById("myNewForm").submit();
}
```

Remember that the `<input type="hidden">` must be given a `name` attribute which will be passed to the page that is receiving the form. You must also give it an `id` attribute which will be used by the `getElementById` in the function.  These do *not* have to be the same, so I recommend you set the `id` to something obvious and unique.

If somebody has a better, simplier, cleaner solution - I would be genuinely interested to see it, as I don't think the above is great, but should work.